# Why "Linux Generic" use RPM extension in MySQL download page?

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, mysql, rpm

I need to install MySQL 5.5 from source in Ubuntu 10.04.

So I'm trying to find tar.gz source from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/#downloads).

But when choosing "Linux Generic" from the drop down menu, it is showing an RPM extension

I wonder why? Can we install from source using RPM package in Ubuntu now? It's like a joke but this prevents me from installing it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to compile from source as you stated in your question, you should not choose "Generic Linux" from the drop down menu. Instead, choose "Source Code" and download the "Generic Linux (Architecture Independent), Compressed TAR Archive".

Extract the compressed tar file and read the instructions on how to compile and install.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert an rpm to a debian package with [alien (1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/alien.1p.html) and install the converted debian package afterwards.

For your more general question many Distributions use the rpm format to install packages. Using rpm as a common base can make sense if you don't add specific dependencies, e.g. you provide static linked binaries. On the other hand there are still `tar.gz` files available (scroll down to the bottom) as well as packages directly for Ubuntu. But these files probably contain binaries and no source code. Check out uthers answer re. source code.

A answer on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/78574) suggested a [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~nathan-renniewaldock/+archive/ppa) containing MySQL 5.5 even for 10.04. You may consider using the provided repository instead of manually installing the package yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Scroll down in the list, the RPM's are listed at the top, the TAR archives are at the bottom, example **Linux - Generic 2.6 (x86, 64-bit), Compressed TAR Archive** is at the bottom of the list